# Android Sqlite WHERE clause not working as anticipated

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this as my query:

```
public Cursor getQuests(int level) {
    final String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ID, "title", "minUC", "maxUC", "xp", "ep", "request", "loot", "level", "numHits", "numHitsReq"};
    return db.query(QUESTS, columns, "level<=\"" + level + "\"", null, null, null, KEY_ID + ", level");
}
```

So, I have entries up to level 10 in my database.  This query works normally up to a point,  while players level is less than 10 everything works as expected, however when player is level 11 or higher the query only returns rows where level = 1.

When I remove the escaped quotes around level it returns an empty cursor.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to post your DB info... especially your creation SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to the fact the LEVEL column in the database is text/string.  Then you are comparing it to another string:

```
"1" <= "11"
"10" <= "11"
"11" <= 11"

but

"2" > "11"
```

However if you are to compare the values, you'll get the expected results

```
1 <= 11
2 <= 11
and so on
11 <= 11
```

Change the database column to INTEGER and remove the quotes around *level* in your query - and you'll be fine.

Comment: sqlite doesn't give me that option, it is set as NUMERIC in sqlite, but the fact that I have to wrap my int (else it simply returns an empty cursor) in quotes makes me think it is being interpreted as a string, and I can't seem to get around that

Comment: Try running your query in a command-line sqlite browser - without the quotes - and see if you get the correct results.  If yes, then the issue is somewhere else in the query.

Comment: Huh?  You most certainly can set a column to be an integer.

Comment: So I ran `SELECT _id, title, level FROM quests WHERE level <= "11"` (with and without the quotes around the number) and both times it returned the proper result... just making me more confused

Comment: The you should definitely remove the quotes in your query and search for the issue elsewhere. I'd say, the code should be something like `db.query(QUESTS, new String[] {KEY_ID, "title", "minUC", "maxUC", "xp", "ep", "request", "loot", "level", "numHits", "numHitsReq"}, "level<=" + level, null, null, null, KEY_ID + ", level")`

Comment: just a side question on your above formula what is the result of "6" <= "5" because when level is five it only shows quests up to level 5... as per your last answer when I do that it returns an empty cursor, so I wouldn't know where else to look

Comment: ok, figured it out... forgot to upload my database revisions into eclipse, level column was not set to numeric... sorry for the trouble, marked as right

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using the "prepared statement paradigm", i.e. trying like below:

```
final String table = QUESTS;
final String columns = {
    KEY_ID,
    "title",
    "minUC",
    "maxUC",
    "xp",
    "ep",
    "request",
    "loot",
    "level",
    "numHits",
    "numHitsReq"
};
final String constraint = "level<=?";
final String constraintArgs = {
    Integer.toString(level)
};
final String groupBy = null;
final String having = null;
final String orderBy = KEY_ID + ", level ASC";

db.query(table, columns, constraint, constraintArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

You might want to change the sort order (from ASC to DESC) depending on how you want it. Also I am assuming that you inject the actual level as an integer to your function. If not so, you might want to change the `constraintArgs` from `Integer.toString(level)` to something else.

The point is that this way you let the sqlite database engine to decide how to interpret the level value.

Comment: I tried your method, and still get the same problem, everything as expected until level hits 10, then it only shows level 1 quests... at level 20 it show quests up to level 2, at level 30 level 3 and so on...  Why can't I force an int value into the query?

Comment: I see @Aleks could help you solve your problem (yeay!!! :) Nevertheless I would still recommend you to read up a bit on prepared statements and such when you find yourself with 10 minutes of free time. You get it (or a subset of it) for free in the Android SQLiteDatabase object when you query with separated constraint arguments (the '?'-mark notation in my example) and it offers you a great deal of security for free (like SQL injection etc.).